# Error when using 'yield' with assert_in in nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I'm using [nose](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/) and I'm having troubles when using `assert_in` with `yield`.

Here's the code that causes the problem:

```
for row in rows:
    yield assert_in, existing_name, row[self.search_field]
```

The error:

```
Failure: ValueError (no such test method in <class 'nose.tools.trivial.Dummy'>: runTest) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ValueError (no such test method in <class 'nose.tools.trivial.Dummy'>: runTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/maroun/.virtualenvs/ads_management/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 289, in generate
    yield MethodTestCase(test_func, arg=arg, descriptor=g)
  File "/home/maroun/.virtualenvs/ads_management/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 345, in __init__
    self.inst = self.cls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class 'nose.tools.trivial.Dummy'>: runTest   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have a workaround, simply define my own `assert_in`:

```
def assert_in(a,b):
    if not a in b:
        raise AssertionError("%r not in %r" % (a, b))
```

For some reason, this *works*. What causes the problem? I have a feeling that it's a nose bug, can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [testing-in-python mailing list](http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2009-April/001805.html):

> The problem is with what you're yielding as the test callable. The
>   "functions" in nose.tools are actually bound methods of a singleton
>   unittest.TestCase. You *can't* safely yield them directly as test
>   callables, because to nose they look like what they are, and therefore
>   nose tries to run the test case that contains them.
>
> Your example will work fine if you define your own assert_true:
>
> ```
> def assert_true(arg):
>     nt.assert_true(arg)
> ```
>
> and yield that instead.

This problem seems only happens in test classes: http://asciinema.org/a/11071